Chemical potential, zero of energy, extensivity
It occurred to me today that I cannot reconcile the notion that the chemical potential, $\mu_i$ of a species in solution is, like energy, defined only up to an additive constant. This is implied in the definitions of standard state chemical potential, that chemical potentials must be referenced to a standard state, etc. However, chemical potential is defined as being the rate of change of the energy of a system with respect to change in particle number (fixed $S$ and $V$) or, equivalently, the change in the Gibbs function at fixed $T$ and $p$ with respect to particle number. If so, then the chemical potential seems to correspond to a change in energy, which should be independent of the choice of the zero of energy.
As an illustration, consider the following diagram from Atkins' Physical Chemistry:
$G$ vs. $n_A$ showing the chemical potential $\mu_A$ as the slope of the function at the point $a$." />
An additive constant to the value of G would shift the function up or down but not change the slope of the graph at any point, and, seemingly, leave the value of the chemical potential at that point unaltered.
Additionally, extensivity demands:
$$U = TS -pV + \sum_i \mu_i n_i$$
Since all extensive and intensive variables above are absolute (assuming my understanding of chemical potential is correct), then $U$ should also be absolute. This implies that the chemical potentials must be defined only up to an arbitrary constant, since we know that U is only defined so. Nevertheless, a graph of $U-TS+pV = G$ vs. $n_i$ (all other properties held constant) would seem to indicate that the chemical potential is absolute at a point $n_i = n$.
Clearly I am missing something, but what exactly is it?

$U/n$, $G/n$, and $\mu$ are all defined only up to an arbitrary constant. Moreover, you could tack on an arbitrary constant to $U$, and it wouldn’t change our definitions for $T$, $P$, and any other intensive variables, or any equation of state. Most of your question presents supporting arguments for this, so I don’t understand the statement in the middle that “all extensive and intensive variables above are absolute”. Perhaps you could clarify.

@Chemomechanics I find the question very clear. The formula derived from the Euler theorem does not contain differences in variables. In this sense, it contains absolute quantities. This was another example of a perfectly reasonable question closed without good reason, and Ján Lalinský's answer shows that it was possible to understand this question clearly.

From the First and the Second law of thermodynamics, and assuming $U$ is function of $S,V,N$, we can only derive the relation
$$
dU = TdS -pdV +\mu dN.
$$
Imagine we start with a system in state described by values $S_0,V_0,N_0$ and "grow it" to a greater size, into a state described by values $S,V,N$, while $T,p,\mu$ are kept constant.
We can integrate both sides of the above expression, assuming $T,p,\mu$ are held constant, from the "small system" reference state $S_0,V_0,N_0$ to some other "big system" accessible state $S,V,N$, to get change of internal energy.
We get
$$
U-U_0 = T(S-S_0) -p(V-V_0) +\mu(N-N_0).
$$
We can rewrite this as
$$
- U + TS -pV + \mu N = -U_0 + TS_0 -pV_0 + \mu N_0.
$$
Quantities $V_0,N_0$ and $T,p$ for a given reference state are definite and there is no arbitrariness to them. But not so for $U_0, S_0$ and $\mu$; their values can be chosen in different ways.
In particular, their values can be chosen in such a way so that the right hand side is zero, and  then we get the implication
$$
U= TS -pV + \mu N \tag{*}
$$
for any accessible state. Thus we get functions $U(S,V,N)$ that are homogeneous functions of first degree, having zero value when $S,V,N$ are zero.
This condition is not a necessary part of definition of internal energy in First law, but it is customary and useful in thermodynamics to impose it on the function $U(S,V,N)$ (when we already understand the concept of entropy and consider internal energy as function of entropy, volume and number of particles).
Let's adopt this constraint and consider only functions $U(S,V,N)$ obeying it. Then, values $U,S,\mu$ for a given state are still arbitrary to an extent. If we change values for the reference state $U_0,S_0,\mu$ to $U_0+\delta U,S_0+\delta S,\mu+\delta \mu$, then we have new values for any other accessible state as well: $U' = U+\delta U$, $S'= S+\delta S$, $\mu' = \mu+\delta\mu$. These so-redefined quantities can still obey the constraint (*) if:
$$
\delta U = T\delta S +\delta \mu~ N.
$$
In other words, within the constraints of (*), change of definition of internal energy and entropy implies definite change of chemical potential
$$
\delta \mu = \frac{\delta U - T\delta S}{N}.
$$

the chemical potential seems to correspond to a change in energy, which should be independent of the choice of the zero of energy.

Yes, but it is not only zero of the Gibbs energy $G$ that is being chosen, but the whole function $G(T,p,N)$. Thus while chemical potential is always
$$
\mu = \frac{\partial G}{\partial N}\bigg|_{T,p}~~~,
$$
value of this depends on how we define $U,S$. If definitions of $U,S$ change, $G$ can change as well, and so does $\mu$:
$$
\mu' =  \frac{\partial G'}{\partial N}\bigg|_{T,p} = \frac{\partial (G + \delta U - T\delta S)}{\partial N}\bigg|_{T,p} 
$$
$$= \mu + \frac{\partial (\delta \mu~ N)}{\partial N} = \mu + \delta \mu .
$$

Your rewriting $U-U_0 = T(S-S_0) -p(V-V_0) +\mu(N-N_0)$ as $- U + TS -pV + \mu N = -U_0 + TS_0 -pV_0 + \mu N_0$ has a problem. In the first formula $T$, $p$, and $\mu$ are functions of $S,V,N$ evaluated at $S_0,V_0,N_0$. In the second formula they are used as if they were the function evaluated at $S,V,N$ .

@GiorgioP-DoomsdayClockIsAt-90 I don't see it. $T,p,\mu$ are assumed to be constant parameters. They have the same value at all points of the integration path connecting $S_0,V_0,N_0$ to $S,V,N$. This is so in both equations. In other words, symbols $T,p,\mu$ have the same meaning in both equations.

They do not have only the same meaning but also the same value. As coefficients of a differential form, they give the orientation of the tangent plane at $S_0,V_0,N_0$. On another point, their values are different.

@GiorgioP-DoomsdayClockIsAt-90 That's what I'm saying, they have the same value on all points of the integration path. Of course, their values are equal to values of partial derivatives of $U$ at all points of that path. Partial derivatives of $U$ may have different values from $T,p,\mu$ at other points, not on the integration path.

I do not understand this. The integration path may be whatever we like. Moreover, U, as a function of S, is a convex function. This implies that $T$ must be a monotonic function of S. It is enough that the path goes from one value of S to another to ensure that $T$ is different. Furthermore, at the level of differential, there is no integration at all. It is just a function depending on $S,S_0.V,V_0,N,N_0$

@GiorgioP-DoomsdayClockIsAt-90 No, in my argument above, the path can't be whatever, it has to follow the path on which $\partial U/\partial S = T,\partial U/\partial V = -p, \partial U/\partial N=\mu$, as the integration in the SVN space from point $S_0,V_0,N_0$ to point $S,V,N$ describes "growing" the system from small size to a bigger size, while keeping intensive properties constant.

Ok. only now I understand that you are scaling the extensive variables of the "small" state using the same scale factor.

@GiorgioP-DoomsdayClockIsAt-90 the integration does not necessarily scale the variables by the same factor. Only when we impose the condition that $-U_0 + TS_0 -pV_0 + \mu N_0$ is zero, we get $U$ as homogeneous function of first degree, and integration has the same effect on $S,V,N$ as scaling them by the same factor.
